# Setup Xcode's GIT for static and Drupal webpages

Tags: git, xcode4, dreamweaver

How can I setup my Xcode 4's SCM for static and Drupal webpages? Most of the time, I'll use Dreamweaver to edit my static webpages. Whereas, I'll use Xcode for php editing. And using CSSedit for css files

I am Lion. I work alone at the moment.

I would prefer GIT.

I have tried creating repository of my working folders. Repository created, it has "branches" and "remote". It does not has any files of my working folders.

Comment: "I am Lion. I work alone at the moment." This is typical behavior for male lions, sure. I would suggest, however, a cooperative effort, given your name is Jessica.

Answer (score 0):

Let me see if I understand: You want to use the Git installation that comes with Xcode 4 in order to manage your static and dynamic site content, which you edit and maintain with a variety of tools.

This probably belongs on superuser.com, since it's not really a coding question.

In any case, Git itself works the same, no matter who it hitched a ride with during installation. You can install Git on its own without going through Xcode by downloading the official stand-alone installer [here](http://git-scm.com/download). Xcode's Git integration (same as its Subversion integration) places a basic GUI wrapper around Git but is heavily geared toward Xcode projects, etc.

If you're using a variety of tools and not "mostly Xcode", you're probably better off using a more focused Git GUI tool. The free Mac app [GitX](http://gitx.frim.nl/) should work better for you than Xcode in this case. I personally use [Tower](http://gitx.frim.nl/) (not free). Whatever the case, since Xcode installs Git (the basic tool / command-line), you don't need to install the standalone separately. For proof, type "man git" in the Terminal.

I hope this helps.